# How do I combine scenes for a small animation?

Tags: animation, scene

I want to make a small animation that will be made up of 3-4 scenes.  How do I combine these?  I'm using blender 3.1 and am rendering in cycles.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: do you mean all scenes at the same time or one after another?

Comment: If there are cuts between each clip of each scene, you can composite them in an external software (Final Cut Pro, iMovie, etc.) or even Blender itself. Export each scene animation first, then compile them all in a video editing workspace inside Blender (or externally), and export them as one video.

Comment: You could render each scene and then edit the clips using the video editor or you could append all  your scenes inside one 3D project. But you need to provide more info and describe exactly what you are after.

Comment: Each scene or clip will be one after the other.  To briefly and simply sum up what the final result should be, the first clip is a pair of hands burying a seed, the next clip is a tree growing, the next clip is two people standing next to tree.  Do I create these as separate files or can I create them all using the same file and then sequence / combine them somehow in blender?

Comment: I just duplicated my self :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
For each scene add a *Scene* (top-right row) ...

[image]

[image]

... and one more for combine them, because you cant add 3D scene into it self). In this last empty Scene switch layout to Video Editing and add strips type Scene into your timeline.

[image]